# Return boolean on Select query using jdbctemplate in Spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, compiler-errors, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to return a `boolean` based on some business. I'm using the jdbctemplate here.

```
public boolean dealExistsInInterval(String partyId) {
    String sql = "<Query>";
    boolean result = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {partyId}, 
            new RowMapper<boolean>() { --> **Error here**
                public boolean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Date startDate = rs.getDate("BBORIGINDATE");
                    logger.info("Start date :"+startDate);
                    Date todayDate = new Date();
                    long diff = todayDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
                    Properties properties = BBUtil.getProperties();
                    int NO_OF_DAYS = 0;
                    if (properties != null) {
                        NO_OF_DAYS = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("NO_OF_DAYS"));
                    }
                    logger.info("NO_OF_DAYS:"+NO_OF_DAYS);
                    logger.info("Number of days between today and latest deal :"+TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) < NO_OF_DAYS ? true : false;
            }
    });
    return result;
}
```

The compile time error occurs at `new RowMapper<boolean>()`.

P.S: This is not a query based on count. After getting the result set, I'm have to execute some business logic.

Comment: Primitive types can't be used as generic type arguments. You need to use the wrapper type: Boolean.

Comment: @JB Nizet, can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Replace `RowMapper<boolean>` by `RowMapper<Boolean>`. And **read** the error messages from the compiler.

Comment: @Jb Nizet Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a generic specification of a primitive data type. You'll have to use the `java.lang.Boolean` wrapper class:

```
new RowMapper<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        // Code goes here...
```